# dynamically created webpage does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a webpage which first creates a number of select forms. When the user selects an option for a particular select form another subform is created depending on the user choice, and appended to that selectform. Unfortenately my code does not work, e.g., (1) the subforms are not created and (2) the selectors for appending the subforms are not coded correctly- they always point to a fixed value (#wrapper-options3). My original code is more complex, but I copied the structure + some simple example functions in the code below - and it causes the same errors as the original code. How should I code the adding of subforms (in Step 2 in code below) correctly? E.g., how to get the right selector values for #wrapper-options?

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var previous;

        //functions
        var Buildform = function(i){
            var form;
            form = '<select class="eprodtype'+i+'" name="transport'+i+'">';
            form += '<option value="bike"> Bike'+i+' </option>';
            form += '<option value="car"> Car'+i+' </option>';
            form += '</select>';
            form += '<div id="wrapper-options'+i+'"> "wrapper-options'+i+'" </div>';
            return $(form);
        }//Buildform

        var Buildsubform = function(i){ //i will contain <select> value 
           var subform = '<p> '+i+' </p>';
           console.log('Buildsubform():'+subform);
           return $(subform);
        }

        //step 1: build 'base' form with multiple select forms
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            var form = Buildform(i);
            $('#wrapper').append(form);

        }

        //step 2: build subform depending on choice user within base form
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
          $(".eprodtype"+i).focus(function () {
            // Store the current value on focus and on change
            var previous = this.value; //old select value
          }).change(function() {

          var subform = Buildsubform(this.value);
          console.log('append subform'+subform);
          //ERROR IN THE NEXT 2 LINES; selector '#wrapper-options'+i always has a value #wrapper-options3 - instead of a dynamic value
          $('#wrapper-options'+i).html(''); //remove previous subform
          $('#wrapper-options'+i).html(subform);
          var str = '#wrapper-options'+i;
          console.log('wrapper-options val: '+str);
          console.log('change eprod val: '+this.value);

          previous = this.value;
       });
        }//for i

    }); //$(document).ready  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <div id="wrapper"></div> <!--wrapper for function Buildform() -->
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Where's your <form> tag?

Comment: Could you consider using lowercase first letters for the function names? This is burning my eyes :_(

Comment: you are right a formtag was missing; just updated the code below, but that does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `.change()` function has a different scope that the code wrapping it since it fires on an event, and not inline. So when it runs, it has no idea what the value `i` is. You need to pass the function a value to get the correct reference, otherwise it will always be that last value of `i` since the wrapping code has finished executing.

Also, you may want to look at using relative selectors and doing away with numbering your elements.

Comment: thnx, I already suspected what you saying, but my question then is: how to get the correct reference value giving my design goal? that's what I struggle with...

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check out [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for reference.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var previous;

        //functions
        var Buildform = function(i){
            var form;
            form = '<form><select class="eprodtype'+i+'" name="transport'+i+'">';
            form += '<option value="bike"> Bike'+i+' </option>';
            form += '<option value="car"> Car'+i+' </option>';
            form += '</select>';
            form += '<div id="wrapper-options'+i+'"> "wrapper-options'+i+'" </div></form>';
            return form;
        }//Buildform

        var Buildsubform = function(i){ //i will contain <select> value 
           var subform = '<p> '+i+' </p>';
           console.log('Buildsubform():'+subform);
           return subform;
        }

        //step 1: build 'base' form with multiple select forms
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            var form = Buildform(i);
            $('#wrapper').append(form);

        }

        //step 2: build subform depending on choice user within base form
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            $('body').on('focus', ".eprodtype"+i, function () {
            // Store the current value on focus and on change
            var previous = this.value; //old select value
          }).on('change', ".eprodtype"+i, function() {

          var subform = Buildsubform(this.value);
          console.log('append subform'+subform);
          //ERROR IN THE NEXT 2 LINES; selector '#wrapper-options'+i always has a value #wrapper-options3 - instead of a dynamic value
          $('#wrapper-options'+i).html(''); //remove previous subform
          $('#wrapper-options'+i).html(subform);
          var str = '#wrapper-options'+i;
          console.log('wrapper-options val: '+str);
          console.log('change eprod val: '+this.value);

          previous = this.value;
       });
        }//for i

    }); //$(document).ready  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <div id="wrapper"></div> <!--wrapper for function Buildform() -->
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thnx. However, but with your code (correction) it still doesnt work

Comment: Without knowing what exactly you are tying to achieve, it's difficult for me to make it work as you expected. Just wanted to give you some direction to move towards. Since your form element is all dynamic, simply binding focus and change to those elements will not work.

Comment: sorry, my previous reaction perhaps sounded a bit blunt. Certainly appreciate your suggestions (!). What I want to achieve is that a subform is created (using Buildsubform() for each dropdownlist and attached to this list. The dropdownlist is created dynamically (using Buildform()) as the number of dropdownlists can vary. The subform will vary depending on the choice in a dropdownlist

Comment: don't get me wrong. I'm not unhappy about your comment at all and I knew my code did not bring what you want (I compared the console results in two versions and nothing changed). One obvious error with my code is that "this.value" in .on() callback will not work as the the delegate method is being used here. Checkout the manual of jquery .on and .delegate and I'm sure you can find what you need. Good luck:)